# Will javascript on server side run if js is disabled on the client side?

Tags: javascript, serverside-javascript

If javascript is disabled in a client browser, will the server side javascript still run?

Comment: Simple, but equivalent question: *Does the server hardware continue to run even if the client is switched off?*

Comment: Thank you man for that simple question.

Comment: Yes. I thought it would be necessary because you seem to be missing the point of "server side" vs. "client side".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Server side code (whether in JS or any other language) is executed and the output it sent to the client.

Then, if there is any JS in that output, it will be executed by the client if that client supports JS and doesn't have it disabled or otherwise blocked.

Comment: so browser properties like navigator.geolocation cannot be accessed if javascript is disabled even if I do it on server-side?

Comment: Yes. The server side JS environment has no access to the browser JS environment. The only thing the two environments have in common is that you are using the same programming language.

Comment: So that means HTML 5 geolocation cannot be used on server side?

Comment: Yes. The server has no direct access to most of the technology that a device uses to know where it is (such as a phone's onboard GPS).

Answer (score 0):

Server-side stuff is run on the server. The clients settings do not affect it.

Comment: So if I disable my js on my browser.My server-side js can be still executed by a browser?

Comment: Server-side JavaScript is *never* executed by the browser. It's executed by the server; this is why it's *called* "server-side".